# How to call a function with two arguments in python

Tags: python

i wanna ask about how to call a function with two arguments in python. for example,
code below is an example i want to call color function.

```
def color(object):
    return '\033[1;34m'+object+'\033[1;m'
tes = 'this must be blue'
print color(tes)
```

but that's just for one argument alone. 
then I want to make the two arguments together with a selection of different colors.
This below for my dummy code.

```
def color(object,arg2):
    blue = '\033[1;34m'+object+'\033[1;m'
    red = '\033[1;31m'+object+'\033[1;m'
tes = 'this must be blue'
tes_2 = 'i wanna this string into red!!' 
print color(tes,red)
```

well, that's just my dummy code and which would be an error like this..

```
print color(tes,red)  
NameError: name 'red' is not defined
```

Can you tell me how to make a well-functioning in python?? ty

Comment: write `red = ` instead of `tes_2 = `

Comment: What do you actually want `color(arg1, arg2)` to return?

Comment: depending on what I define a new variable.
just the color that comes out it can be called with two arguments. with the already defined in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small but fundamental errors in your second block:

1. Your arguments are `object` and `arg2`. `object`is a reserved python word, both words are not so explanatory and (the real mistake) you never use `arg2` in your function.
2. You don't used any `return` value in the function.
3. When you call the function, you use `color(tes,red)` when it should be `color(tes,tes_2)`.

I have rewritten the block, take a look (with some modifications you can fine-tune later)

```
def color(color1,color2):
    blue = '\033[1;34m'+color1+'\033[1;m'
    red = '\033[1;31m'+color2+'\033[1;m'
    return blue, red

tes = 'this must be blue'
tes_2 = 'i wanna this string into red!!' 
for c in color(tes,tes_2):
    print c
```

An alternate suggestion to achieve what you want would be:

```
def to_blue(color):
    return '\033[1;34m'+color+'\033[1;m'

def to_red(color):
    return '\033[1;31m'+color+'\033[1;m'

print to_blue('this is blue')
print to_red('now this is red')
```

EDIT: as requested (this is just the beginning ;oP . For example, you could use a dictionary of color names and color codes to call the function)

```
def to_color(string, color):
    if color == "blue":
        return '\033[1;34m'+color+'\033[1;m'
    elif color == "red":
        return '\033[1;31m'+color+'\033[1;m'
    else:
        return "Are you kidding?"
        #should be 'raise some error etc etc.'

print to_color("this blue", "blue")
print to_color("this red", "red")
print to_color("his yellow", "yellow")
```

Comment: how about call the function in accordance with what we want to specify?
def color(object,The second argument to specify the color that we want, example:red):
ty

Answer (score 1):

```
def color(object,arg2):
    blue = '\033[1;34m'+object+'\033[1;m'
    red = '\033[1;31m'+arg2+'\033[1;m'
    return blue + red
tes = 'this must be blue'
tes_2 = 'i wanna this string into red!!' 
print color(tes,tes_2)
```

I think you should visit [Python2.7 Tutorial](http://localhost/python/python-2.7.2-docs-html/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: please don't use object as a variable name, it's a builtin.

Answer (score 1):

The `red` variable is defined inside of `color`, so you can't use it outside of `color`.

Instead, you have the variables `tes` and `tes_2` defined, so the call to `color` should look like `print color(tes, tes_2)`.